# Todonotes: group list-of-todos by section

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft, todonotes

This is a follow up question to [group list-of-todos by chapter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61036/todonotes-group-list-of-todos-by-chapter). egreg's solution works great with `classicthesis` and `scrreprt`, and I've been trying to do the same without `classicthesis` and for `scrartcl`, i.e. add group the list of todos by section.

The code below is directly based on egreg's code and almost works, although it always adds the title of the last section as well, even when there is no todonote. So this is the first thing I need help fixing, and secondly there is probably an easier way to do this rather than using code based on `classicthesis`.

I'm not wed to `tocloft`, but I quite like it for customisations (which are not in this MWE).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{todonotes,tocloft,xpatch,hyperref}

% This is based on classicthesis chapter definition
\let\oldsec=\section
\renewcommand*{\section}{\secdef{\Sec}{\SecS}}
\newcommand\SecS[1]{\oldsec*{#1}}%
\newcommand\Sec[2][]{\oldsec[\texorpdfstring{#1}{#1}]{#2}}%

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61267/11984
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\Sec}{\addtocontents{tdo}{\protect\todoline{\thesection}{#1}{}}}{}{}
\newcommand{\todoline}[1]{\@ifnextchar\Endoftdo{}{\@todoline{#1}}}
\newcommand{\@todoline}[3]{%
  \@ifnextchar\todoline
    {}
    {\contentsline{section}{\numberline{#1}#2}{#3}{}{}}%
}
\let\l@todo\l@subsection
\newcommand{\Endoftdo}{}

\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{tdo}{\string\Endoftdo}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\listoftodos

\tableofcontents

\section{My first Section}\todo{Section 1 note}
\subsection{A first Subsection}
\subsubsection{A first subsubsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note 2}
\section{My second Section}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 1 note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 2 note}
\section{A section without notes}
\subsection{A subsection without notes}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection without notes}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a possible solution; only information for sections with `\todo` notes will be written to the List of Todos:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{todonotes,xpatch,hyperref}

% initial definitions for storing the section info (name and number)
\def\thissectiontitle{}
\def\thissectionnumber{}

\newtoggle{noTodos}

\makeatletter
% redefinition of \@sect so \section glbally stores its name and number 
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
\let\@svsec\@empty
\else
\refstepcounter{#1}%
\protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
\fi
\@tempskipa #5\relax
\ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
\begingroup
#6{%
\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
\interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
\endgroup
\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
\fi
#7}%
\else
\@xsect
\def\@svsechd{%
#6{\hskip #3\relax
\@svsec #8}%
\csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
\fi
#7}}%
\fi
\@xsect{#5}%
\ifnum#2=1\relax
\global\def\thissectiontitle{#8}
\global\def\thissectionnumber{\thesection}
\fi%
}

\pretocmd{\section}{\global\toggletrue{noTodos}}{}{}

% the \todo command does the job: the first time it is used after a \section command, 
% it writes the information of the section to the list of todos
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\todo}{%
    \iftoggle{noTodos}{
     \addtocontents{tdo}{\protect\contentsline {section}%
        {\protect\numberline{\thissectionnumber}{\thissectiontitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noTodos}
        }{}
    }{}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listoftodos
\tableofcontents

\section{My first Section}\todo{Section 1 note}
\subsection{A first Subsection}
\subsubsection{A first subsubsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note 2}

\section{My second Section}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 1 note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 2 note}

\section{A section without notes}
\subsection{A subsection without notes}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection without notes}

\section{My fourth Section}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 1 note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 2 note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks and explanations

1. This is basically an adaptation of [`my answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52747/3954) to [Include chapters in List of Figures with titletoc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52746/3954-)
2. The `\todo` command does the job and decide if the section info will be written to the List of Todos; whenever the `\todo` command is used in the document, it will examine a boolean flag; if the boolean is false, then it adds the section information to the List of Todos and sets the boolean to true; otherwise, it does not add any information.
3. The `\section` command was also modified to reset the boolean.
4. `\@sect` was modified to globally store the information about the corresponding title and number for the section; this information will then be used when writing to the List of Todos.

### Version using `titlesec`

In the comments it has been mentioned that the `titlesec` package is being used (which might produce undesired results with KOMA classes; see [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954)). In this case, using the `explicit` option the code simplifies considerable, since now there's no need to hook into `\@sect` to retrieve the name and number for sections:
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{todonotes,xpatch,hyperref}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

```
% initial definitions for storing the section info (name and number)
\def\thissectiontitle{}
\def\thissectionnumber{}

\newtoggle{noTodos}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
  {\thesection}
  {0.5em}
  {\gdef\thissectiontitle{#1}\gdef\thissectionnumber{\thesection}#1}

\pretocmd{\section}{\global\toggletrue{noTodos}}{}{}

% the \todo command does the job: the first time it is used after a \section command, 
% it writes the information of the section to the list of todos
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \xpretocmd{\todo}{%
    \iftoggle{noTodos}{
     \addtocontents{tdo}{\protect\contentsline{section}%
        {\protect\numberline{\thissectionnumber}{\thissectiontitle}}{}{} }
      \global\togglefalse{noTodos}
        }{}
    }{}{}%
  }

\begin{document}

\listoftodos
\tableofcontents

\section{My first Section}\todo{Section 1 note}
\subsection{A first Subsection}
\subsubsection{A first subsubsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 1, section 1, subsection note 2}

\section{My second Section}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 1 note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 2 note}

\section{A section without notes}
\subsection{A subsection without notes}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection without notes}

\section{My fourth Section}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 1 note}
\subsection{Another subsection}\todo{Section 2, subsection 2 note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for this. So much for me thinking that it can be done "easier" `:-)`. Three notes/comments: 1) Why is there a `\thissectiontitle` after the first section? 2) There is an unnecessary white space between `{\thissectionnumber} {\thissectiontitle}`. 3) Is a global redefinition of `\@sect` not dangerous (for other tocs/lof/lot etc., `titlesec` or other packages)

Comment: @Jörg 1) It's just a leftover from initial tests, I've deleted it now. 2) Those spaces are hermless, but I've alos deleted them. 3) It's perfectly safe as long as you stay within the default settings. It's not recommended to use `titlesec` with KOMA classes (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954); if you, however, are planning to use this package, the code will simplify considerably since there will be no need to hook into `\@sect`. Let me know if you want to see a version of the code with `titlesec`, although, as I said before, it's not recommended to use the package with KOMA classes

Comment: Yes, I'm using `titlesec` for some documents (I'm aware of the "problems" with KOMA, but so far I have not managed without it on some more tricky layouts). If you can add an alternative simplified version that would be great - I was about to ask why this code is quite a bit more complicated than that in your Chapters-in-LOF answer.

Comment: @Jörg It's more long because internally `\section` uses `\@startsection` which "hides" the commands really used to produce sections (in the case of chapters the commands are explicit). In some hours I'll add a version with `titlesec` (I'm short of time right now).

Comment: @Jörg I had some time, so I've updated my answer with the code using `titlesec`.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to hook `\gdef\thissectiontitle{#1}\gdef\thissectionnumber{\thesection}` into titleformat without changing a previously defined titleformat of a section?

Comment: @Jörg I don't understand your question. If you already used `\titleformat`, simply incorporate the `\gdef`s in that definition in the last mandatory argument (as I did in my example). Or perhaps do you mean something else? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Assume that I want a dedicated package that makes the adjustments above (with `titlesec`). This package should just use the previously defined section titleformat and add the `\gdef`s without a need to reformat titleformat (sorry, hard to explain in the comments here).

Comment: But I think I found a solution: `\apptocmd{\ttl@select}{\gdef\thissectiontitle{#4}\gdef\thissectionnumber{\thesection}}{}{}`. I believe that hooks in the `\gdef`s at the highest possible level. This also means that `explicit` is not required, but possible.