# Centering of equations in classicthesis style

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, classicthesis

I'm using the `classicthesis` package. Unlike math in `$$`, an `equation` is not centered:

```
\begin{equation}
mod(\zeta, G) := \sum_{C \in \zeta} \left ( \frac{\omega(C)}{\omega(E)} - \frac{vol(C)^2}{4 \omega(E)^2} \right )
\label{eq:mod}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

I'd like an equation to be centered with respect to the column by default.

My preamble looks as follows:

```
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{minted}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % standard latex math font
%\usepackage{cmbright}
%\renewcommand\rmdefault{hfoldsty}



\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e} % algorithms
\usepackage{scrextend}  % addmargin command comes from here
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{subcaption}    % TODO: doesn't cooperate with subfig
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174186/todonotes-group-list-of-todos-by-section
\usepackage{tocloft,xpatch}




%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% COMMANDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% formatting
\newcommand{\term}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\algo}[1]{\textsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\TODO}[1]{\todo[size=\small, inline]{#1}}

% math
\newcommand{\set}[1]{ \{ #1 \} }

% function definition
\newcommand{\funcdef}[2]
{
    \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            #1 \\
            #2
        \end{array}
    \right.
}


\newcommand{\nwk}{\textsf{NetworKit}\xspace}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  ENVIRONMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{koan}
{\color{darkgray} \begin{addmargin}[6cm]{0cm} \begin{footnotesize}}
{\end{footnotesize} \end{addmargin} \bigskip }


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  THEOREMS
%------------------------------------------ ----------------------------------------------

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%  CONFIG
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\graphicspath{ {graphics/} }
%\graphicspath{{../Graphics}}

% include needed for pseudocode includes
\input{Pseudocode/Distributed/pseudocodes_setup}

% include needed for TeX-generated plots
\input{graphics/Distributed/plots/plots_setup}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Colors
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.985,0.985,0.985}

\newenvironment{code}[1]
                {
                \begin{minted}[mathescape,
                               linenos,
                               numbersep=5pt,
                               frame=lines,
                               framesep=2mm,
                               fontsize=\footnotesize,
                               bgcolor=codebg]{#1}
                }
                {\end{minted}}
```

Options to documentclass:

```
\documentclass[
        twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
                footinclude=true,cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
                ngerman,american, % Languages
                ]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: Do you mean `classicthesis`, the package? Please share your preamble as well.

Comment: [Your equation appears to be centered for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nybOg.png), also when loading the `classicthesis` package. Is your Tex Live distribution up to date?

Comment: It isn't (Tex Live 2014), but is that likely to be the issue? Okay, will upgrade anyway.

Comment: Let us know if that fixes the issue. :)

Comment: Did a complete update of everything TeX-related. No changes.

Comment: What about your `\documentclass` command, are you loading any options there?

Comment: I suspect you have a `fleqn` option to `\documentclass`

Comment: Nope, see above

Comment: Can you please add a MWE that shows your problem? Because if I puzzle together your code fragments, I get a centred equation.

Comment: I still get it centered, even using your `\documentclass` with all the options. Also, read your warnings: you have unused options (namely, `correction, paper type and font size`) and some conflict between your KOMA-script class and `titlesec`.

Comment: @samcarter A "minimum" working example of this multi-file project is not so easy to post here and will not be small. What happens if you include my `classicthesis-config.tex` instead of the default? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6849a7d9ac2ac3891126

Comment: @Alenanno These warnings don't tell me much and I don't know how they may possibly relate to the centering of equations.

Comment: @clstaudt In your GIST there is `\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}`.  Remove this line.

Comment: @HenriMenke That's it!

Comment: No a minimal working example of a multi-file project ***would*** be small. That's the point. You keep taking stuff out until you have just enough code to reproduce the problem. In this case, you would presumably have solved the issue by that point and wouldn't even need to post. Instead, you posted a question which failed to include the code responsible for the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as the question asks about a problem which depends on code not included here and is therefore unlikely to be of any help to future readers.